# Why would ExecuteReader crash reading a specific data field of certain records, when ExecuteScalar works fine?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I've got an ASP.NET webforms site using C# and .NET 4.0.

I've created a class for loading information from a SQL table into an object, which has been working fine for a while.  Recently a couple of specific records crash the `SqlDataReader` I use to populate this class with a database timeout error.  I can't find any reason for these records to crash the reader.

I've isolated the crash to the [Address] `int` type datafield that when excluded from the query, the reader works fine. I've checked the database and the values stored are not unusual, and changing them to 0, null, or other working data, still results in a timeout error.  If I call the fields using `ExecuteScalar()`, the data populates properly without error.

**What could be causing this behavior?**

Here is the content of the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

***Source Method***

```
    public void Populate(Guid UserId)
    {
        DAL db = new DAL();
        using (SqlConnection con = db.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand RowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([UserId]) FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId", con);
            RowCount.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
            RowCount.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;

            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT [ApplicationId],[UserId],[Password],[PasswordFormat],[PasswordSalt],[MobilePIN],"+
                "[Email],[LoweredEmail],[PasswordQuestion],[PasswordAnswer],[IsApproved],[IsLockedOut],[CreateDate],[LastLoginDate],[LastPasswordChangedDate],[LastLockOutDate]," +
                "[FailedPasswordAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart],[Comment]," +
                "[FirstName],[LastName],[Address] FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                int Rows = (int)RowCount.ExecuteScalar();
                if (Rows > 0)
                {
                    rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())                        
                    {
                        this.ApplicationId  = (Guid)rdr["ApplicationID"];
                        this.UserId = (Guid)rdr["UserId"];
                        this.Password = common.Coalesce(rdr["Password"], "");
                        this.PasswordFormat = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordFormat"], 0);
                        this.PasswordSalt = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordSalt"], "");
                        this.MobilePIN = common.Coalesce(rdr["MobilePIN"], "");
                        this.Email = common.Coalesce(rdr["Email"], "");
                        this.LoweredEmail = common.Coalesce(rdr["LoweredEmail"], "");
                        this.PasswordQuestion = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordQuestion"], "");
                        this.PasswordAnswer = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordAnswer"], "");
                        this.IsApproved = (bool)rdr["IsApproved"];
                        this.IsLockedOut = (bool)rdr["IsLockedOut"];
                        this.CreateDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["CreateDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastLoginDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLoginDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastPasswordChangedDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastPasswordChangedDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastLockOutDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLockOutDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptCount"], 0);
                        this.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount"], 0);
                        this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.Comment = common.Coalesce(rdr["Comment"], "");
                        this.FirstName = common.Coalesce(rdr["FirstName"], "");
                        this.LastName = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastName"], "");
                        this.Address = common.Coalesce(rdr["Address"], 0);
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { if (con != null) { con.Close(); } throw ex; }
            finally { if (con != null) { con.Close(); } }
        }
    }
```

Here's the modified method that doesn't error.

```
    public void Populate(Guid UserId)
    {
        DAL db = new DAL();
        using (SqlConnection con = db.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand RowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([UserId]) FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId", con);
            RowCount.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
            RowCount.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;

            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT [ApplicationId],[UserId],[Password],[PasswordFormat],[PasswordSalt],[MobilePIN],"+
                "[Email],[LoweredEmail],[PasswordQuestion],[PasswordAnswer],[IsApproved],[IsLockedOut],[CreateDate],[LastLoginDate],[LastPasswordChangedDate],[LastLockOutDate]," +
                "[FailedPasswordAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart],[Comment]," +
                "[FirstName],[LastName] FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                int Rows = (int)RowCount.ExecuteScalar();
                if (Rows > 0)
                {
                    rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())                        
                    {
                        this.ApplicationId  = (Guid)rdr["ApplicationID"];
                        this.UserId = (Guid)rdr["UserId"];
                        this.Password = common.Coalesce(rdr["Password"], "");
                        this.PasswordFormat = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordFormat"], 0);
                        this.PasswordSalt = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordSalt"], "");
                        this.MobilePIN = common.Coalesce(rdr["MobilePIN"], "");
                        this.Email = common.Coalesce(rdr["Email"], "");
                        this.LoweredEmail = common.Coalesce(rdr["LoweredEmail"], "");
                        this.PasswordQuestion = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordQuestion"], "");
                        this.PasswordAnswer = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordAnswer"], "");
                        this.IsApproved = (bool)rdr["IsApproved"];
                        this.IsLockedOut = (bool)rdr["IsLockedOut"];
                        this.CreateDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["CreateDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastLoginDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLoginDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastPasswordChangedDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastPasswordChangedDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.LastLockOutDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLockOutDate"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptCount"], 0);
                        this.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount"], 0);
                        this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                        this.Comment = common.Coalesce(rdr["Comment"], "");
                        this.FirstName = common.Coalesce(rdr["FirstName"], "");
                        this.LastName = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastName"], "");
                    }
                    rdr.Close();

                    string sqlQuery2 = "SELECT [Address] FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, con);
                    sqlCommand2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
                    sqlCommand2.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserId;
                    this.Address = common.Coalesce(sqlCommand2.ExecuteScalar(), 0);
                }
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { if (con != null) { con.Close(); } throw ex; }
            finally { if (con != null) { con.Close(); } }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are using.. need to see if you are Adding Parameters and if you using or checking the correct datatype but can't really tell by reading your issue..

Comment: You say it is a timeout error but the error message is a network error message?

Comment: You don't need all that funky `con.Close()` code in the `catch` clause. Just let the code in the `finally` clause do its work, or simplify the whole thing and use a `using` construct.

Comment: Incidentally, editing your question to whip it into shape was more work than it should have been.

Comment: I've posted the code that errors, with the code I'm using as a work around.

Comment: First off, SqlCommand and SqlReader both implement IDisposable, you should warp those calls in using clauses.  Second, does the error occur on the first calls out or is it only occuring after a certain number of calls are made?

Comment: Also, Why would you execute a query to get the count of users with a matching id then immediately go get all of the data for that ID?  Seems like a total waste.  Just execute your second query, if it has data you can do what you need to do.

Comment: Finally, you don't need to do any try .. catch logic to clean up the connection.  The using clause does that for you.

Comment: Usually I get this error message:        `Server Error in '/' Application.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Comment: @Stanton: I understood that part.  But is it happening on the *first* request or is it randomly occurring after the app has been running for awhile.

Comment: Thanks for the info about using statements.  The error occurs whenever a specific record is called, I've identified 2 records that will error, regardless of the number of calls made.  Also, I query to count the rows to prevent DBNull from crashing the program.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what if you changed the order the fields are read back from the reader.  Put address at the top.  I wonder if your common.Coalesce method is doing something to wack the reader due to a failure on the lastname??

Comment: I've commented out the other parameters and only pulled the address in the query, it still crashes on the same 2 records.  The commom.coalesce is checking for null or empty and returning the value if false.

Answer (score 3):

You should show us more of your code than this, i assume that this is only a consequential error.

Normally  opening  already opened connections or closing  already closed connections results in an `Invalid Operation Exception` and this is what you're doing here.

```
try{
    con.Open();
    //do something
    con.Close(); //will be closed when no error was raised
}catch (Exception ex){
    if (con != null){
        // this will close if the error was raised in "do something"
        con.Close(); 
    } 
    throw ex; // you better thow the exception by throw (instead of throw ex) to keep the stacktrace
}finally {
    if (con != null) {
        // this will definitely cause an Invalid Operation Exception since the connection was already closed
        con.Close(); 
    }
}
```

You should instead use the [using-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to close and dispose the connection implicitely. If you want to close it manually, you should also check it's [ConnectionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state.aspx):

`if (con != null && con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed){con.Close();}`

An example which circumvents this with using-statement:

```
try{
    using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)) { 
        using(var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(command, con)){
            con.open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()) { 
                //do something
            }
        }
    }//will automatically close connection
}
catch (Exception ex) { 
    //log exception and/or throw
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I'm with @Tim on this one, but you are far from the first to fall in to this hole. Suggest you read up on cached connections in ADO.Net and sql server. Unless you turn them off, it will take care of all this gubbins for you. You'll be able to see the wood for the trees then as well.

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted the Error, and thats the code contained in the error.  I've edited the post to include the function calling the database.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your code a bit, cleaned it and added Using Statements. now the connections would close as they need to. BTW, you were trying to add a UserId parameter twice. Here's how it looks like now. a bit easier to read:

```
public void Populate(Guid UserId)
    {
        DAL db = new DAL();
        using (SqlConnection con = db.GetConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT [ApplicationId],[UserId],[Password],[PasswordFormat],[PasswordSalt],[MobilePIN]," +
                "[Email],[LoweredEmail],[PasswordQuestion],[PasswordAnswer],[IsApproved],[IsLockedOut],[CreateDate],[LastLoginDate],[LastPasswordChangedDate],[LastLockOutDate]," +
                "[FailedPasswordAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart],[Comment]," +
                "[FirstName],[LastName],[Address] FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE [UserId]=@UserId";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = UserId });
                try
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                this.ApplicationId = (Guid)rdr["ApplicationID"];
                                this.UserId = (Guid)rdr["UserId"];
                                this.Password = common.Coalesce(rdr["Password"], "");
                                this.PasswordFormat = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordFormat"], 0);
                                this.PasswordSalt = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordSalt"], "");
                                this.MobilePIN = common.Coalesce(rdr["MobilePIN"], "");
                                this.Email = common.Coalesce(rdr["Email"], "");
                                this.LoweredEmail = common.Coalesce(rdr["LoweredEmail"], "");
                                this.PasswordQuestion = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordQuestion"], "");
                                this.PasswordAnswer = common.Coalesce(rdr["PasswordAnswer"], "");
                                this.IsApproved = (bool)rdr["IsApproved"];
                                this.IsLockedOut = (bool)rdr["IsLockedOut"];
                                this.CreateDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["CreateDate"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.LastLoginDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLoginDate"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.LastPasswordChangedDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastPasswordChangedDate"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.LastLockOutDate = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastLockOutDate"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptCount"], 0);
                                this.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount"], 0);
                                this.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = common.Coalesce(rdr["FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart"], DateTime.Now);
                                this.Comment = common.Coalesce(rdr["Comment"], "");
                                this.FirstName = common.Coalesce(rdr["FirstName"], "");
                                this.LastName = common.Coalesce(rdr["LastName"], "");
                                this.Address = common.Coalesce(rdr["Address"], 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**UPD**: i've edited the code, to ignore the counting of rows, and modified the line  `common.Coalesce(rdr["Address"], 0);`

Comment: Your code is nice. I added the UserId parameter twice because there were 2 separate SqlCommands.  It looks like your code only needs 1 though, if the rdr.HasRows works properly.  Although, the problem I'm having isn't a connection drop issue, its a problem with sqldatareader crashing on a specific data record, out of hundreds of records. However pulling the same data with an executeScalar doesn't error.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Stanton if it's a record connected to some Id, try to make the same request in the SQL management studio, maybe the data is corrupted in some way, and can not give the reader a proper Data Set. another thing that I see in you code is that in the first example if the address value is null, you are trying to set it to an empty string, and in the second example, you are passing it a 0. and you did say that it's an [int] Type.

Comment: I've ran the query in SQL MS with out issue. I've also changed the fields values to test for corruption. The fields work fine with ExecuteScalar(),  but error with ExecuteReader().  Also, thanks for pointing out the empty string, that was a typo created when I recreated the error code for this question. It was originally a 0 passed by the coalesce method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run SQL Profiler and attach it to your database to watch the queries come across and get the responses.

You might also execute your query directly in Management Studio.

I'm wondering if there isn't a covering index that the first query is pulling data from that is somehow corrupted.

Either way, the profiler ought to give you a few more hints.

---

Regarding the initial rowcount select.  I don't understand your comment about it being there to protect against dbnulls and program crashes.  If a record doesn't exist for that ID then when the call to `while(reader.read()) { .. }`  isn't going to enter that branch, which is all your rowcount test is preventing.

Comment: The query works fine in Management Studio,  I'm not sure how to use SQL profiler so I'll look it up.

Comment: If I excecuted the while(reader.read()) code and there was no rows returned I would receive an  `object reference not set to an instance of the object` type error.

Comment: @Stanton: I know this is a side issue, but ??  what line would throw that?  reader.read() returns true if there is a record.  If nothing was returned then it should return false and never even go into that code block.  I've never seen it be true when zero records were returned...

Comment: To be honest I was really confused when it started happening and instead of dwelling on it, I did the row count work around.  It could have been an issue from another class that I copied over when creating this class.

Comment: Looks like SQL Profiler isn't an option with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.  When I open the profiler there's an error message requesting I use standard or better editions of SQL to install integration services first.